# How do I construct the oracle for a general Bernstein-Vazirani circuit?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-circuit, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

Say I have a secret of length $n$, $s = |x_{n-1}x_{n-2}...x_0 \rangle$. If I want to construct an oracle for this problem would I just insert a CNOT gate on every qubit where the secret's value is 1? And just do nothing to all of the 0 qubits?

How would I determine the asymptotic complexity of this circuit in its worst-case situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is right. If you think about it, $CNOT|x\rangle |s\rangle = |x\rangle|x \oplus s \rangle \ $. Thus, giving a secret bitstring $s = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n$ where $s_i \in \{0,1\}$, then whenever $s_i$ is non-zero ($s_i = 1$), performing a CNOT gate between the ancilla qubit and the $ith$ qubit in your input qubits (note that you have $n$ input qubits and one ancilla qubit in your circuit) is equivalent to performing $x_i \cdot s_i $.

Thus, everywhere there is a non-zero element in your secret bitstring $s = s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n $ you apply a CNOT gate between the ancilla qubit and the $ith$ input qubit. And anywhere the secret bitstring is zero, you don't do anything.

---

For example: Suppose your secret bitstring is $s = 0110$ then you would have the following circuit.

[image]

---

The worst case scenario is when your secret bitstring is non-zero every where. $s = 111\cdots 1$. In such case, you have to perform $n$ CNOT gates. But note that, on a quantum computer, not all the qubits are connected. So you can't just perform CNOT gate between any pair of qubit you pleased, you need to do some **swapping**.

For instance, look at the qubit layout in `ibmq_16_melbourne`
[image]

you can see that qubit 0 is not connected directly to qubit 13. Hence, to perform a CNOT between qubit 0 and 13, you would need to [SWAP](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.SwapGate.html) qubit 13 and 14 first, perform the CNOT, then SWAP it back... so the actual circuit running on current hardware will be longer than what you see on paper.